# PHP Class / OOP : When to "reference" a class within a class vs extend a class?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, parent, extends

When is it ideal to:

```
class USER {
    // stuff about user
}

class PROFILE extends USER {
    // stuff about user's profile
}
```

and when is it ideal to:

```
class USER {
    $id;
    $profile;

    function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->profile = new PROFILE($id);
        // set profile variables
    }
}

class PROFILE {
    $id;
    // other variables pertaining to profile

    function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

I feel more comfortable with the 2nd example?  Are there any specific caveats I should be aware of?

Should I be thinking of one as not mutually exclusive subsets and the other as children?

Answer (score 2):

This is the classic question of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

**Use encapsulation:**

- When you want to provide *some* of the functionality of the base class, but want to hide some of it.
- When you want to extend / modify the functionality of the base class, but don't need it to be type-compatible.

**Use inheritance:**

- When you need derived classes to be type-compatible with the base class. In other words, if the client code will need to refer to instances of `Derived` with `Base` references.

In your example, it doesn't make sense for PROFILE to derive from USER. A user *has* a profile, but a profile *is not* a user.  For this example, it makes sense for the USER class to contain a PROFILE field.

Comment: Can I assume encapsulation would be good for extending a class to deal with a new protocol?  And would it make sense to have the USER class extend the DB class which contains connectivity functions for a db?

Comment: Sure, but something like that would require the base class to provide some sort of common functionality that the derived class would use. If the new class is entirely different, but you want to treat it like you did the first protocol-handling class, then you want to define an Interface or Abstract base class, that both protocols derive from.

Comment: I like this explanation. For those new to OOP, ask yourself if the inherited class "is a" parent class. For example, "is a profile a user?" The answer is no, so it does not extend USER. If instead, it matches with the question "has a" then it's likely to be an attribute/property. For example, USER "has a" PROFILE.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the real way to do it would be:

```
class User {

    private $id,
            $profile;

    public function __construct($id, Profile $profile) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->profile = $profile;
    }

}

class Profile { ... }

new User(42, new Profile(...));
```

You don't want to extend a class, unless there's a clear hierarchy (`Admin extends User`).
You should also not *couple* classes like you did in your `User` constructor, rather use dependency injection as shown above.

Comment: so if I wanted to create a user but hold off on creating a profile I can just have Profile $profile = NULL as a default in the USER constructor?  And inject it manually later if I wanted to?  I do see your point about coupling classes and why it wouldn't work but there are going to be times that I want to create a profile object without yet associating it with a user.  Or rather there will be times when I don't want to access the user's profile, just the basic info about the user like id and password.

Comment: Well, in your example every user has a profile by default, and you don't even have control over what that profile is because it's constructed by default in the user's constructor. It's the same thing, really. But by injecting the profile into the user's constructor, you have more control over what that profile is. You can subclass/extend the `Profile` class for different kinds of profiles. You can mock it for unit testing. If your business rule is that each user has to have a profile, require one in the constructor. If it may be optional, make it optional through `Profile $profile = null`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, unless you can say that a `PROFILE` is just a special kind of `USER`, and in all cases can be treated just like a `USER`, you don't want to use inheritance to model the relationship.  A `USER` might *have* a `PROFILE`, or a `PROFILE` might be *associated with* a particular `USER`, but the two are distinct entities -- so neither one should inherit from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Usually parent classes are more like generic classes that you are going to extend and rarely use by their own. So inheritance is more like the way it is supposed so be: you extend a generic class.

I'm not gonna go for the animal metaphor again but something like:

```
class USER {} // generic class

class ADMIN extends USER {} // specific class

class MOD extends USER {} // specific class
```

has a logic because we extend a generic USER class to specify a class for each type of user.

For anything else that is not hierarchical I'd use encapsulation.